# Using Asyncio loop reference in another file

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Hi I have the following script, that listens to Google pubsub messages and in the callback I'm passing the messages to another script with loop parameter.

In the second script, I have a task with dependent future function. But future function never gets called.

```
import os, time
import base64, json
import asyncio
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
from app.libs.pubsub.pubsub_connect import PubsubConnect
from app.config import config
from evergage.scripts.evga_process import initEvga
from app.utils import log

LOG = log.get_logger()

PROJECT_NAME = config.get('pubsub', 'project_name')
SUBSCRIPTION = config.get('pubsub', 'insights_subscription')


class PubsubConsumer(PubsubConnect):

    _subscriber = None

    def __init__(self, loop):
        self._subscriber = self.getClientService()
        #loop.create_task( self.getMessages(loop) )
        self.getMessages(loop)


    def getMessages(self, loop):

        def consumeMessageTask(message):
            #loop.create_task( self.callback(message, loop) )
            loop.call_soon( self.callback(message, loop) )


        subscription_path = self._subscriber.subscription_path( PROJECT_NAME, SUBSCRIPTION )
        flow_control = pubsub_v1.types.FlowControl(max_messages=10)
        self._subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=consumeMessageTask, flow_control=flow_control)

        #loop.run_forever()


    def callback(self, message, loop):

        pubSubMsg = message.data.decode("utf-8")
        pubSubMsg = json.loads( base64.urlsafe_b64decode( pubSubMsg) )

        if pubSubMsg['verb']['display'] == 'evga_upsert':
            loop.create_task( initEvga(pubSubMsg, loop) )

        message.ack()


asyncLoop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
test = PubsubConsumer(asyncLoop)
asyncLoop.run_forever()
asyncLoop.close()
```

Second file evga_process.py

```
import os, time
import base64, json
import asyncio
import functools
from app.config import config
from app.utils import log

LOG = log.get_logger()
MKTO_BATCH = {
    'count': 0,
    'total': 5,
    'data': []
}


async def getMarketoData(cookies):
    #await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    tmpData = []

    for cookie in cookies:
        tmpData.append("test-" + cook)

    return tmpData


def initSalesforce(future, param1):
    result = future.result()
    LOG.info( param1 )
    LOG.info( str(result) )
    pass


def initEvga(pubSubMsg, loop):
    pubSubID = pubSubMsg['id']
    upsertInfo = pubSubMsg['object']['definition']['description']

    MKTO_BATCH['data'].append(pubSubID)

    MKTO_BATCH['count'] += 1

    if MKTO_BATCH['count'] == MKTO_BATCH['total']:
        mktoTask = loop.create_task( getMarketoData(MKTO_BATCH['data']) )
        mktoTask.add_done_callback( functools.partial( initSalesforce, "myparam1") )

        MKTO_BATCH['count'] = 0
        MKTO_BATCH['data'] = []
```

I tried with even simple code, but its not working. It works only, If I call like this

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
task = loop.create_task( test_task(loop) )
initEvga(loop)
task.add_done_callback(got_result)
```

Am I missing anything here?

---

Updated script in single file

```
async def heartbeat1():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("heartbeat 1")

async def heartbeat2():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("heartbeat 2")


class PubsubConsumer(PubsubConnect):

    _subscriber = None

    def __init__(self, loop):
        self._subscriber = self.getClientService()

    def getMessages(self, loop):

        def consumeMessageTask(message):
            #loop.create_task( self.callback(message, loop) )
            #loop.call_soon( self.callback(message, loop) )
            PubsubConsumer.callback(message, loop)

        subscription_path = self._subscriber.subscription_path( PROJECT_NAME, SUBSCRIPTION )

        #subClient.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=PubsubConnect.callback)
        # Limit the subscriber to only have ten outstanding messages at a time.
        flow_control = pubsub_v1.types.FlowControl(max_messages=10)
        self._subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=consumeMessageTask, flow_control=flow_control)

        #loop.run_forever()

    @staticmethod
    def callback(message, loop):
        time.sleep(1)
        pubSubMsg = message.data.decode("utf-8")
        pubSubMsg = json.loads( base64.urlsafe_b64decode( pubSubMsg) )

        loop.create_task( heartbeat2() )

        message.ack()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

loop.create_task( heartbeat1() )

psClient = PubsubConsumer(loop)
psClient.getMessages(loop)

loop.run_forever()
loop.close()
```

Both heartbeat1() and heartbeat2() is calling fine. But, if I remove heartbeat1() call, then heartbeat2() also not firing.

What is the reason? and If I keep the heartbeat1() always running, does it create any issues?

Thanks,
Bala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is definitely incorrect:

```
mktoTask.add_done_callback( functools.partial( initSalesforce, "myparam1")
```

You can't send an async function to `add_done_callback`, which expects a regular function. When invoked, an async/coroutine function returns a coroutine object without executing any of the code inside. To actually execute the code, the coroutine object must be submitted to an event loop. In your case, it will be dropped instead without ever executing the code inside the function. (This is much like calling a generator, but never passing the returned iterator to something that will extract values out of it.)

What you need is something like:

```
async def initEvga(pubSubMsg):
    ...
    if MKTO_BATCH['count'] == MKTO_BATCH['total']:
        await getMarketoData(MKTO_BATCH['data'])
        await initSalesforce("myparam1")
    ...
```

Now that `initEvga` is a coroutine, start it from `callback` using:

```
loop.create_task(initEvga(pubSubMsg))
```

...or, if the callback is invoked from a different thread:

```
asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(initEvga(pubSubMsg), loop)
```

(You don't need to pass `loop` to asyncio functions, they can always obtain the running event loop by calling `asyncio.get_event_loop()`.)

Finally, `loop.call_soon(self.callback(message, loop))` doesn't make sense because `call_soon` accepts a function to call, and the above code is calling it with the *result* of `self.callback()`, which is invoked immediately. You need either:

```
self.callback(message, loop)
```

or something like:

```
loop.call_soon(self.callback, message, loop)
# or loop.call_soon_threadsafe if called from a different thread
```

Since in both cases `callback` must be short and non-blocking, there seems to be no benefit in postponing it, so I'd choose the first variant.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment. I tried as per your suggestion, but still the async is not firing. I'm pasting one more script, please have a look.

Comment: @Balakumar Is your `callback` getting invoked? Is the event loop running correctly? You can test that the event loop is not blocked by adding a `loop.create_task(heartbeat())` at the beginning, with `heartbeat` being defined as something like `async def heartbeat(): while True: await asyncio.sleep(1); print("heartbeat")`

Comment: Thanks again. You are correct, please see the question after the <hr> break. I have added everything in a single file with 2 heartbeat functions. If I remove the heartbeat1(), then nothing working, why?

Comment: You might have misunderstood the heartbeat suggestion - the idea is to have only *one* heartbeat, so that you know the event loop is functioning. Also, using `time.sleep()` (or any blocking call) is a programming error in asyncio because it blocks the event loop.

Comment: @Balakumar I think I have an idea: given that having a heartbeat somehow helps your event loop, I am guessing that your callback is getting called from a different thread, so the event loop doesn't know that it needs to wake up. What happens when you print `threading.current_thread()` in `callback`?

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. I have removed the time.sleep and thanks for the explanation. threading.current_thread() giving me like `<Thread(ThreadPoolExecutor-SubscriberPolicy_4, started daemon 5484)> <Thread(ThreadPoolExecutor-SubscriberPolicy_7, started daemon 2400)>`

Comment: Is it because of google pub/sub? `DEBUG:google.cloud.pubsub_v1.subscriber.policy.thread:Using <function PubsubConsumer.getMessages.<locals>.consumeMessageTask at 0x0000020440CE0E18> to process new message received:`

Comment: Do you understand anything from here https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/pubsub/subscriber/index.html#subscription-callbacks

Comment: @Balakumar That's it - instead of `loop.create_task(initEvga(...))`, use `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(loop, initEvga(...))`.

Comment: Thanks user4815162342, you made my day. One small correction, loop is second parameter `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(initEvga(...), loop)`

Comment: @Balakumar No problem! I've now amended the answer to mention the threading issue. Feel free to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) if the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Those who are looking for the answer. Here is the final script.

```
async def initEvga(pubSubMsg):
    pubSubID = pubSubMsg['id']
    print(pubSubID)
    return pubSubMsg['id']


class PubsubConsumer(PubsubConnect):

    _subscriber = None

    def __init__(self):
        self._subscriber = self.getClientService()

    def getMessages(self, loop):

        def consumeMessageTask(message):
            PubsubConsumer.callback(message, loop)

        subscription_path = self._subscriber.subscription_path( PROJECT_NAME, SUBSCRIPTION )
        flow_control = pubsub_v1.types.FlowControl(max_messages=10)
        self._subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=consumeMessageTask, flow_control=flow_control)

        loop.run_forever()

    @staticmethod
    def callback(message, loop):
        pubSubMsg = message.data.decode("utf-8")
        pubSubMsg = json.loads( base64.urlsafe_b64decode( pubSubMsg) )
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(initEvga(pubSubMsg), loop)
        message.ack()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
psClient = PubsubConsumer()
psClient.getMessages(loop)
loop.close()
```